# Getting keys that were updated with the using a dictionaries update method

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, key

Is it possible to get the keys that where changed when using the update method?

```
def func(**kw):
    d = {'key0' : 0, 'key1' : 1}
    d.update(**kw)

func(kw0=0, kw1=1)
```

In the above code I'd want to get the keys **'kw0'** and **'kw1'**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, once `update()` is called, they are indistinguishable from the other keys.

Inside the function you can still look at `kw.keys()` to see which ones were passed in

eg

```
def func(**kw):
    d = {'key0' : 0, 'key1' : 1}
    d.update(**kw)
    print "updated %s"%kw.keys()

func(kw0=0, kw1=1)
```

Comment: Wow, that was way more obvious than I would have thought. Thanks!

Comment: But if you run `func(key0=0)`, then 'key0' is printed in spite of the fact, that dict `d` was not changed.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to detect the keys that were changed, is to store a copy of original dict, and then compare updated version, and original version.

```
def func(**kw):
    d = {'key0' : 0, 'key1' : 1}
    old = dict(d)
    d.update(kw)
    changed_keys = [key for key in d if old.get(key) != d.get(key)]
    print changed_keys
```

Comment: To be absolutely correct, you would use `is not` rather than `!=`. That would be the ones which are changed. But that could or could not be what is desired - object equality could be the only desired metric.